# Can you take a heap snapshot with Safari's Web Inspector?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, web-inspector

Chrome has a 'Take Heap Snapshot' action in the 'Profiles' tab of its dev tools. For the life of me I can't find an equivalent feature in the Safari Web Inspector (I've looked in both Safari and WebKit).

Is this feature simply not available? If that's the case, is there any alternative for taking a heap snapshot of a WebView in an iOS app?

Answer (score 3):

Safari uses JSC as the Javascript engine and as far as I know it has no support for heap snapshots.

Comment: Trying to develop for iOS browsers is a nightmare. This is just the tip of the iceberg :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using the Memory timeline in the Timelines tab. See the blog post for full details: https://webkit.org/blog/6425/memory-debugging-with-web-inspector/

Comment: This doesn't exist for JSContext on macOS.